# 3d surface plot with (-1, -1, 0) coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

Here is my code for 3d surface plot with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = $x$
        , ylabel = $y$
        , zlabel = Test
        , xmin = -1
        , xmax = 1
        , ymin = -1
        , ymax = 1]
   \addplot3
   [
    surf
   ,  faceted color=blue
   , samples  = 15
   , domain   = -1:1
   , y domain = -1:1
   ]
    {776.062 -50.812* x + 153.062 * y -76.812 *x *y};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder how to get coordinates `(x, y) = (-1, -1)` rather than `(x, y) = (1, -1)`. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like `y dir=reverse`?

Comment: Thanks @jake for your helpful comment. It should be  `x dir = reverse`.  I would appreciate if you make your comment as an answer so I can accept it future reference. Thanks

Comment: so did [3D surface in pgfplots with given data](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88877) get resolved?

Comment: Yes, @cmhughes. I resolved it.

Comment: ok, thanks for letting us know- will flag to close it as too localized (unless you wish to self-answer it) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question, you want the x-y coordinates to be -1,-1 in the front.
You could achieve this with the plot option `x dir = reverse`.
[image: x dir = reverse]

or, if you want to keep a right handed coordinate system, you can use the plot option`view={-70}{30}`

[image: view={-70}{30}]

Reversing the x/y/z direction is rather self explaining.

The option `view={azimuth}{elevation}` rotates the plot, horizontally and vertically, in degrees.
For the rotation, it is important that a negative sign for the rotation implies an inverse view direction.

Answer (score 5):

You can reverse the direction of an axis by setting, for example, `x dir=reverse`:

[image]

Comment: @MYaseen208: I think you should accept user24276's answer instead of mine. It's more complete, and therefore more likely to help other people who come across this problem

Comment: Okay @jake, I accepted his answer. Anyhow thanks for your help too.