# Plotting x + y + z = 1 or other such graphs

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot the graphs of different surfaces, all of with are along the lines of "x + y + z = 1", but I cannot figure out how I would go about plotting these equations into latex. If there is a way to plot these graphs with out drawing the lines manually I would appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Sorry, but so far I don't think I know what you want to do. I think it is not simply drawing the surface `x+y+z=1` which would be very simple. Could you add least add a sketch of what would be the desired result by editing your question?

Comment: Implicit equations are not supported by TeX since it requires a CAS. But if you can get the data somehow from other software, pgfplots can draw the contour plots and so on.

Comment: Search the site. For example, [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91335/3d-surface-plot-with-1-1-0-coordinates) has planes, or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52953/intersection-of-two-surfaces) you can find a plane and surface.  If those are not what you want, a more specific question (along with your attempt) will be more likely to get people interested in helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it is easy, because you can invert the equation to

```
z(x,y) = 1 - x - y
```

This can be visualized with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf] {1 - x - y};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]